# Rotating items in a cell by clicking on it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a mutual exclusion toggle without using an onclick button within HTML since my HTML isn't allowed to be changed. Within my javascript I am trying to use event listeners and getting elements by tag name but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

```
window.onload(function () {
    let cells = document.getElementsByTagName(`td`).item(0);

    for (let cell of cells) {
        cell.addEventListener(`click`, rotate);

        function rotate() {
            document.getElementsByTagName(`A`).item(0);
            document.getElementsByTagName(`B`).item(0);
            document.getElementsByTagName(`C`).item(0);
            document.getElementsByTagName(`D`).item(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet for you that adds a listener to each td and makes some function in my case I made it change the inner text of the red box

```js
const td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
const text = document.querySelector('.clicked');

td.forEach( e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', event => {
    text.innerText = e.innerText;
    
    //your function
  })
});
```

```css
table {
width: 90vw;
height: 50vh;

}

td {

  height: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;

}

td:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: grey;
 color: white;
}

.flex{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;

}

.clicked{
 width: 80%;
 height: 20%;
 font-size: 18;
 text-align: center;
 border: 3px solid red;
 padding: 2vh;
 margin: 2vh;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="clicked">TEXT</div>
</div>
```